# Restoring Ubuntu image to a partition on a external drive

Tags: macos, ubuntu, restore, bootable-media

My goal here is to install a bootable version of ubuntu onto a partition on my old ipod photo. Here is what i have done:

- I have been using disk utility to do all of this *

1) Enables disk mode and partitioned my ipod. I have an ubuntu partition and it is formatted as mac osx journaled

2) I have downloaded the ubuntu 10.10 iso

3) The problem - When I try to restore the ubuntu iso to my ubuntu partition, I get the error: Could not validate source - Invalid argument

4) I have tried to verify the iso and it says there is no checksum information

How should I go about fixing this problem? Is it the format of the partition that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstood you, but you should not RESTORE the Ubuntu ISO-file to your partition. You should burn a DVD and boot from it. This will then help you INSTALL Ubuntu on the partition of your choice.